# Heroku node.js redis deploy error

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I'm trying to push my node.js app to Heroku and get the following error:

> ```
>    make: *** [all] Error 1
>    sh: gmake: not found
>    npm ERR! hiredis@0.1.14 preinstall: `make || gmake`
>    npm ERR! `sh "-c" "make || gmake"` failed with 127
>    npm ERR! 
>    npm ERR! Failed at the hiredis@0.1.14 preinstall script.
>    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the hiredis package,
>    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>    npm ERR!     make || gmake
>    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>    npm ERR!     npm owner ls hiredis
>    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
> ```

```
   npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-343-ec2
   npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-v052/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-8OVn/cli.js" "rebuild"
   npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_z7yxzlw3xyyk
   npm ERR! node -v v0.8.7
   npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.49
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/build_z7yxzlw3xyyk/npm-debug.log
   npm ERR! not ok code 0
   !     Failed to rebuild dependencies with npm
   !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "myapp"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  ,"engines": {
        "node": "0.8.x",
        "npm":  "1.1.x"
  }
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": "2.5.8"
    , "jade": ">= 0.0.1"
    ,"ejs" : ">=0.7.1"
    ,"pg": ">=0.8.2"
    ,"moment" : ">=1.7.0"
    ,"async": ">=0.1.22"
    ,"request": ">=2.10.0"
    , "connect-redis": ">= 0.0.1"
    , "redis": ">= 0.0.1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `node_modules` to .gitignore and running `git rm -r --cached .` fixed the problem.

Comment: it would be handy if you could elaborate on how to do that?